# Get network state in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm tying to get the network state in a controller and navigate to s state, when the user is offline.

I've installed ng-cordova.

This is my code:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function() {
    $state.go("error");
    alert("offline")
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function() {
    alert("online")
  });
})
```

I don't get the alert when I'm online and offline. What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you install `$cordovaNetwork` plugin?

Comment: yes @TomislavStankovic

Comment: Which error do you get in Console (F12)?

Comment: No errors in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Cordova plugin add `cordova-plugin-network-information`
Then `window.Connection` for Checking available internet.

```
if(window.Connection){
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      $state.go("error");
        alert("offline")
       }else{
            console.log(navigator.connection.type);
              alert("online")
        }
    }
```